# cannot update after adding new source

Tags: pi-2, apt, terminal, source.list

I am running a raspberry Pi 2B (with GUI disabled) and I added `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi` to my `sources.list`.

After this, I ran `sudo apt-get update` and everything seems to work.

But when I executed `sudo apt-get upgrade`, a few packages could not be installed.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` did not help(same errors), and because of that, I decided to comment my source out again.

That didn't help, I got the same errors:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following packages have been kept back:
  opensc opensc-pkcs11
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
43 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Setting up console-setup-linux (1.193~deb10u1) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package console-setup-linux (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of console-setup:
 console-setup depends on console-setup-linux | console-setup-freebsd | hurd; however:
  Package console-setup-linux is not configured yet.
  Package console-setup-freebsd is not installed.
  Package hurd is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package console-setup (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cups-daemon (1.7.5-11+deb8u6) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up netfilter-persistent (1.0.11) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package netfilter-persistent (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iptables-persistent:
 iptables-persistent depends on netfilter-persistent (= 1.0.11); however:
  Package netfilter-persistent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iptables-persistent (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up rsyslog (8.4.2-1+deb8u3) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package rsyslog (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up binfmt-support (2.2.0-2) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package binfmt-support (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up x11-common (1:7.7+19) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package x11-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxss1:armhf:
 libxss1:armhf depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxss1:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libtk8.6:armhf:
 libtk8.6:armhf depends on libxss1; however:
  Package libxss1:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libtk8.6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tk8.6-blt2.5:
 tk8.6-blt2.5 depends on libtk8.6 (>= 8.6.0); however:
  Package libtk8.6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tk8.6-blt2.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of blt:
 blt depends on tk8.6-blt2.5 (= 2.5.3+dfsg-4); however:
  Package tk8.6-blt2.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package blt (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 1.7.5-11+deb8u6); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
 cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 1.7.5-11+deb8u6); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 1.7.5-11+deb8u6); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up dphys-swapfile (20100506-5) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package dphys-swapfile (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xfonts-utils:
 xfonts-utils depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xfonts-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gsfonts-x11:
 gsfonts-x11 depends on xfonts-utils (>= 1:7.5+2); however:
  Package xfonts-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gsfonts-x11 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python-tk:
 python-tk depends on blt (>= 2.4z-9); however:
  Package blt is not configured yet.
 python-tk depends on libtk8.6 (>= 8.6.0); however:
  Package libtk8.6:armhf is not configured yet.
 python-tk depends on tk8.6-blt2.5 (>= 2.5.3); however:
  Package tk8.6-blt2.5 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python-tk (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of idle-python2.7:
 idle-python2.7 depends on python-tk (>= 2.6~a3); however:
  Package python-tk is not configured yet.
 idle-python2.7 depends on python2.7-tk; however:
  Package python2.7-tk is not installed.
  Package python-tk which provides python2.7-tk is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package idle-python2.7 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of jarwrapper:
 jarwrapper depends on binfmt-support; however:
  Package binfmt-support is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package jarwrapper (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libice6:armhf:
 libice6:armhf depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libice6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libsm6:armhf:
 libsm6:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libsm6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxt6:armhf:
 libxt6:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libxt6:armhf depends on libsm6; however:
  Package libsm6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxt6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxmu6:armhf:
 libxmu6:armhf depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxmu6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxaw7:armhf:
 libxaw7:armhf depends on libxmu6; however:
  Package libxmu6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libxaw7:armhf depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxaw7:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxtst6:armhf:
 libxtst6:armhf depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxtst6:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of x11-utils:
 x11-utils depends on libxaw7; however:
  Package libxaw7:armhf is not configured yet.
 x11-utils depends on libxmu6; however:
  Package libxmu6:armhf is not configured yet.
 x11-utils depends on libxt6 (>= 1:1.1.0); however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.
 x11-utils depends on libxtst6; however:
  Package libxtst6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package x11-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libatk-wrapper-java:
 libatk-wrapper-java depends on x11-utils; however:
  Package x11-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libatk-wrapper-java (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libaudio2:armhf:
 libaudio2:armhf depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libaudio2:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbonoboui2-0:armhf:
 libbonoboui2-0:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libbonoboui2-0:armhf depends on libsm6; however:
  Package libsm6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbonoboui2-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgtkglext1:armhf:
 libgtkglext1:armhf depends on libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0); however:
  Package libice6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libgtkglext1:armhf depends on libsm6; however:
  Package libsm6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libgtkglext1:armhf depends on libxmu6; however:
  Package libxmu6:armhf is not configured yet.
 libgtkglext1:armhf depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgtkglext1:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of x11-xkb-utils:
 x11-xkb-utils depends on libxaw7; however:
  Package libxaw7:armhf is not configured yet.
 x11-xkb-utils depends on libxt6; however:
  Package libxt6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package x11-xkb-utils (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libxklavier16:armhf:
 libxklavier16:armhf depends on x11-xkb-utils; however:
  Package x11-xkb-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libxklavier16:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of liblightdm-gobject-1-0:armhf:
 liblightdm-gobject-1-0:armhf depends on libxklavier16 (>= 5.0); however:
  Package libxklavier16:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package liblightdm-gobject-1-0:armhf (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sat4j:
 sat4j depends on jarwrapper (>= 0.5); however:
  Package jarwrapper is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sat4j (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-common:
 xserver-common depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.
 xserver-common depends on x11-xkb-utils; however:
  Package x11-xkb-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xserver-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tightvncserver:
 tightvncserver depends on x11-common | xserver-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.
  Package xserver-common is not configured yet.
 tightvncserver depends on x11-utils; however:
  Package x11-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package tightvncserver (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of x2x:
 x2x depends on libxtst6; however:
  Package libxtst6:armhf is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package x2x (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xfonts-100dpi:
 xfonts-100dpi depends on xfonts-utils (>= 1:7.5+2); however:
  Package xfonts-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xfonts-100dpi (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xfonts-base:
 xfonts-base depends on xfonts-utils (>= 1:7.5+2); however:
  Package xfonts-utils is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xfonts-base (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xinit:
 xinit depends on x11-common; however:
  Package x11-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package xinit (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up fake-hwclock (0.11) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package fake-hwclock (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up triggerhappy (0.5.0-1) ...
insserv: FATAL: service udev is missed in the runlevels 2 3 4 5 to use service raspi-config
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
dpkg: error processing package triggerhappy (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 console-setup-linux
 console-setup
 cups-daemon
 netfilter-persistent
 iptables-persistent
 rsyslog
 binfmt-support
 x11-common
 libxss1:armhf
 libtk8.6:armhf
 tk8.6-blt2.5
 blt
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
 dphys-swapfile
 xfonts-utils
 gsfonts-x11
 python-tk
 idle-python2.7
 jarwrapper
 libice6:armhf
 libsm6:armhf
 libxt6:armhf
 libxmu6:armhf
 libxaw7:armhf
 libxtst6:armhf
 x11-utils
 libatk-wrapper-java
 libaudio2:armhf
 libbonoboui2-0:armhf
 libgtkglext1:armhf
 x11-xkb-utils
 libxklavier16:armhf
 liblightdm-gobject-1-0:armhf
 sat4j
 xserver-common
 tightvncserver
 x2x
 xfonts-100dpi
 xfonts-base
 xinit
 fake-hwclock
 triggerhappy
```

My `sources.list`:

```
deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie main contrib non-free rpi

#deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main

#deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main 
#deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main

#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
#deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
#deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ buster main contrib non-free rpi
```

output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I've tried the commands from [this post](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=281568) but it did not help.

Comment: It sounds like either you thought you could use buster sources without upgrading, or you thought you were upgrading (but did not follow the right sequence of commands).  That is unfortunate...

Comment: @goldilocks How can I fix this?

Comment: I don't know if you can, and -- eek -- I just noticed the base system was `jessie` (v8), not `stretch` (v9), meaning you tried to skip straight to v10.   This was a very bad idea.  You might want to clarify in the question what you thought you would accomplish by doing this; if there is a fix that information might be relevant.

Comment: I just found the source in another raspberry pi and thought I could install java 11 with it. @goldilocks

Comment: You could `try apt-get -s install $(apt-history rollback | tr '\n' ' ')`. Then remove the buster sources from your apt-sources and do a `sudo apt-get update` again and if your are irish or have the luck of the irish it might work. If you managed the rollback I would suggest to use sdkman to install java. I dont know if this works on a raspbian but this link uses sdkman to install grails on as raspi (grails needs groovy and groovy needs java): https://recursive.codes/blog/post/7

Comment: Here is the source link for the first statement i suggested to you in my last comment . https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79050/can-i-rollback-an-apt-get-upgrade-if-something-goes-wrong

Comment: What *PeterPaulKiefe*r suggested I would only do on a cloned SD Card so you do not risk to completely destroy your installation.

Comment: I had to add the `apt-history` function before executing before executing the command but (after update&upgrade) I still have the same problem. I will see if i can live with this and (if not) I will re-install raspbian.